# My Java client isn't reading the whole Socket response

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, reusability

I'm writing a java-c client-server, where the server is in C and the client is in Java. The socket is reused. I don't know why but the client reads the first response from the socket then loops, it's like the client isn't getting "\n". What am I not getting?
The C server sends the response in the format (length:stringlength:string) etc

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Use: java Client server port");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try{
            BufferedReader fromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.println("Insert input1: ");
            String input1 = fromUser.readLine();

             System.out.println("Insert input2: ");
                String input2 = fromUser.readLine();
            

                Socket s = new Socket(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
                //BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
                InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                BufferedWriter toServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));

            do {
               

                String message = "(" + input1.getBytes("UTF-8").length + ":" + input1 + input2.getBytes("UTF-8").length + ":" + input2 + ")";
                toServer.write(message);
                toServer.flush();
                
                /*reading result from server*/
                //String buff;
                String output = "";
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int read;
                while((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output = new String(buffer, 0, read);
                    System.out.print(output);
                    System.out.flush();
                    
                };

                if(output.charAt(0) != '(' || output.charAt(output.length()-1) != ')'){
                    System.out.println("error using protocol");
                }

                if(output.indexOf(':')<0){
                    System.err.println("error using Canonical S-expression!");
                    System.exit(2);
                }

                for(int i=output.indexOf(":")+1;i<output.length()-2;i++){
                    System.out.print(output.charAt(i));
                }
                System.out.println();


                s.close();

                System.out.println("Insert input1: ('end' to exit)");
                input1 = fromUser.readLine();

            } while(!input1.equals("end"));
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you expect your client to stop looping?

Comment: After reading the whole server output for the specific input!

Comment: How does it know when it's read the whole server output? Your code keeps reading until the socket is closed.

Comment: It's like "while((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1)" isn't working properly.

Comment: It's working properly. `read` returns -1 if the socket is closed. Does the server close the socket after it sends the response?

Comment: No, it should't close the socket because I need to reuse it

Comment: Well then the client still loops, because the client loops until the socket is closed, and the socket isn't closed